# Carets Feature Selection using Genetic Algorithms: How to extract the results?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, r-caret, feature-selection

I am new to carets Genetic Algorithm Feature Selection and started with a simple run on the iris dataset. I want to extract **the best features, their accuracy and also the total number of model trainings** (evaluation of a feature subset). Furthermore i do not understand how the final model is build.

Caret provides a description of the method: https://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-using-genetic-algorithms.html
However, i did not really understand how many model trainings they will need in the end and how the final model is build.

```
library(caret) 

dataset <- iris
levels(dataset$Species) <- c(0, 0, 1)

ga_ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = caretGA, method = "cv", number = 3, verbose = TRUE)
res <- caret::gafs(x = dataset[, 1:(length(dataset)-1)], 
 y = dataset[, length(dataset)],
 iters = 5,
 popSize = 6,
 pcrossover = 0.8,
 pmutation = 0.1,
 gafsControl = ga_ctrl,
 method = "glm", family = binomial(link = 'logit'),
 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
```

I got this output (without setting a specific seed now):

```
Fold1 1 0.96 (2)
Fold1 2 0.96->0.97 (2->4, 50.0%) *
Fold1 3 0.97->0.9788889 (4->2, 50.0%) *
Fold1 4 0.9788889->0.9809091 (2->2, 100.0%) *
Fold1 5 0.9809091->0.98 (2->2, 100.0%)
Fold2 1 0.9718182 (3)
Fold2 2 0.9718182->0.9709091 (3->4, 75.0%)
Fold2 3 0.9718182->0.9718182 (3->4, 75.0%)
Fold2 4 0.9718182->0.9709091 (3->1, 33.3%)
Fold2 5 0.9718182->0.9688889 (3->3, 50.0%)
Fold3 1 0.97 (3)
Fold3 2 0.97->0.9688889 (3->3, 100.0%)
Fold3 3 0.97->0.97 (3->3, 100.0%)
Fold3 4 0.97->0.969798 (3->2, 66.7%)
Fold3 5 0.97->0.9709091 (3->3, 100.0%) *
+ final GA
 1 0.9533333 (1)
 2 0.9533333->0.96 (1->2, 50.0%) *
 3 0.96->0.9533333 (2->2, 100.0%)
 4 0.96->0.98 (2->3, 66.7%) *
 5 0.98->0.9733333 (3->3, 100.0%)
+ final model
```

`res$ga$fit` gives Accuracy 0.96 while `res$fit` gives Accuracy 0.9533333, but the 0.98 should be the correct value, shouldn't it?

For the total number of trainings i suppose it is something like

```
popSize * iters * folds
```

with folds being the number from ga_ctrl, but I am not sure about it.

For the best features, is `res$optVariables` correct?

Answer (score 0):

[image]I agree that documentation on both books (feature engineering and applied predictive) are hard to understand. There are couple of terms which are used interchangeably (eg. iteration vs generation) and make it all a bit ambiguous.

PopSize is one of them: it is unclear whether it refers to the number **or** length of the individuals (chromosomes).

I believe that popSize refers to the initial size of the population (number of individual/chromosomes). I am unsure whether next generations (also name iterations) will have those 50 individuals over and over again. If so, then, you calculations should be correct.

$optVariables should store the best variables. You can also (probably) find them within your final model.
I am running PLS and I can find them on MODEL$fit$finalModel$xNames

The final GA is run against all the observations on your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but, hopefully, useful to others with the same question.

So, by running the code above:

```
library(caret) 

dataset <- iris
levels(dataset$Species) <- c(0, 0, 1)

ga_ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = caretGA, method = "cv", number = 3, verbose = TRUE)
res <- caret::gafs(x = dataset[, 1:(length(dataset)-1)], 
                   y = dataset[, length(dataset)],
                   iters = 5,
                   popSize = 6,
                   pcrossover = 0.8,
                   pmutation = 0.1,
                   gafsControl = ga_ctrl,
                   method = "glm", family = binomial(link = 'logit'),
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
```

So, the result is:

```
> res

Genetic Algorithm Feature Selection

150 samples
4 predictors
2 classes: '0', '1' 

Maximum generations: 5 
Population per generation: 6 
Crossover probability: 0.8 
Mutation probability: 0.1 
Elitism: 0 

Internal performance values: Accuracy, Kappa
Subset selection driven to maximize internal Accuracy 

External performance values: Accuracy, Kappa
Best iteration chose by maximizing external Accuracy 
External resampling method: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 

During resampling:
  * the top 4 selected variables (out of a possible 4):
    Petal.Length (100%), Petal.Width (100%), Sepal.Length (66.7%), Sepal.Width (33.3%)
  * on average, 3 variables were selected (min = 3, max = 3)

In the final search using the entire training set:
   * 4 features selected at iteration 1 including:
     Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width  
   * external performance at this iteration is

   Accuracy       Kappa 
     0.9600      0.9104
```

The accuracy for the optimum variables (`res$optVariables`) will be 0.96. This is the average accuracy at the optimum iteration (`res$optIter`).

So, we can extract this accuracy by:

```
library(tidyverse)
res$averages %>% select(Accuracy) %>% slice(res$optIter)
```

The result will be:

```
> res$averages %>% select(Accuracy) %>% slice(res$optIter)
  Accuracy
1     0.96
```